# Mass Rename Files with bash

Tags: bash, rename, sed

I've got a bunch of numbered files like this:

```
file #01.ext
file #02.ext
file #03.ext
file #04.ext
file #05.ext
```

And what I want is to make them all have three digits (two leading 0's) instead of one, so;

```
file #001.ext
file #002.ext
file #003.ext
file #004.ext
file #005.ext
```

My thought is to use sed to replace the # with #0 (which in my case is good enough, there are no files over #99 yet). All the files are in the same folder, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect files with 3 digits already

```
for f in "file #"*.ext; do
  num=${f#file #}
  num=${num%.ext}
  new=$(printf "file #%03d.ext" $num)
  echo mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

This will display in the console the commands to execute, but not actually rename the files.

Once you are happy with what it intends to do, you can make it rename the files by removing the word `echo` and re-running it.

Comment: This could've saved me a step earlier. I've been doing it all with sed, and used `ls | grep '[0-9]\{3\}' | sed 's|\(.*\)#0\(.*\)|mv "&" "\1#\2"|' | sh` just to make them have two digits, and then did it the way I listed above.

Comment: I've changed this to the answer, now that I'm learning more about all of this, this is more practical and adaptable.

Comment: One can use the -v option to printf: `printf -v new "file #%03d.ext" $num`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need sed for this.  It can be done with a very simple command:

```
rename 's/#0/#00/' *.ext
```

Example:

```
temp$ ls
file #01.ext  file #02.ext  file #03.ext  file #04.ext  file #05.ext
temp$ rename 's/#0/#00/' *.ext
temp$ ls
file #001.ext  file #002.ext  file #003.ext  file #004.ext  file #005.ext
```

Comment: I don't have perl rename installed.

Comment: I lied, I used to not have it installed but I do on this archlinux install.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick from within the folder:

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\)#\(.*\)/mv "&" "\1#0\2"/' | sh
```

Comment: `ls` piped to `sed` piped to `sh`? My brain is melting.

Comment: The you probably don't want to see find piped through grep piped through sed piped to sh. :D

Comment: Any particular reason this is bad?

Comment: In fact, I'd be much better with find -> generate shell code. The reason for this is that find is less likely to mangle filenames than ls. In the real world I'd just use `mmv` for this, or a while read command substitution loop pulling nul-terminated filenames from `find`. Or, if the files are nicely globbable, a simple for loop as glenn used in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hybrid solution:

```
ls | sed -r "s/(.*#)([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)/printf 'mv -v \"&\" \"%s%03d%s\"' \"\1\" \"\2\" \"\3\"/e;e"
```