# Rename every file in a directory to remove part of filename

Tags: linux, command-line, rename, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mass Rename Files with bash](https://superuser.com/questions/352006/mass-rename-files-with-bash)

I have a directory full of files with names like this:

```
1418450360_72733601001_th-72713048001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733606001_vs-72703839001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733607001_th-72703839001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733618001_vs-72709868001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733619001_th-72709868001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733621001_vs-72709874001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733622001_th-72709874001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733629001_vs-72714456001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72733630001_th-72714456001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734162001_vs-72713060001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734163001_th-72713060001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734174001_vs-72714480001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734175001_th-72714480001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734770001_vs-72718313001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734771001_th-72718313001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734776001_vs-72714511001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
1418450360_72734777001_th-72714511001.jpg?pubId=1418450360
```

What's a quick way of renaming all of them to remove the query part?  I.e. from `foo.jpg?bar` to `foo.jpg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it myself:

```
rename 's/jpg?.*/jpg/' *
```